# UI Bootstrap date picker is not working in ng-admin custom page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-admin

I am new to angularjs and also for ng-admin.I am using ng-admin for my project. In that I make custom page in that I have to use UI bootstrap date picker.But popup is not coming. Below is my code.

here is my custom page code.

```
<div class="input-group datepicker">
  <input type="text" ng-model="rawValue" id="" name="{{ name }}" class="form-     control"
  uib-datepicker-popup="{{ format }}" is-open="isOpen" ng-required="{{v}}"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleDatePicker($event)">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
</div>
```

here is my javascript code.

```
 $scope.rawValue = new Date();

 $scope.format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

 $scope.v = true;
 $scope.isOpen = false;

  $scope.toggleDatePicker = function ($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  };
```

Please help me in this regard.

Actually when I include ui-bootsrap.min.js file in "index.html" custom page datepicker is working fine.But ng-admin normal page datepickers and filter popups are not working.

Comment: Is it possible it just a hidden under other elements?  Have you tried using the datepicker-append-to-body=true directive?

Comment: may be you have version problem use bootstrap Version `1.0.3`

Comment: How to know the version of ui-bootstrap in ng-admin. Actually I've checked ng-admin.min.js file but it is not showing the version of ui-bootstrap.

Comment: I've tried with version 1.0.3. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you used `is-open="isOpen"` in your input tag and set `$scope.isOpen = false;` in your controller but when call `toggleDatePicker` function on button click didn't set `$scope.isOpen = true;`

so need to set `$scope.isOpen = !$scope.isOpen;` for toggle

```
$scope.toggleDatePicker = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.isOpen = !$scope.isOpen;
};
```

**NB:** ensure that you injected properly `'ui.bootstrap'` in your module

```
angular.module('yourModuleName', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

**Updated:**

Absolutely you should include `ui-bootsrap.min.js` in **index.html** file because of `ng-admin` didn't include `ui-bootsrap`. So your module will be like :

```
angular.module('yourModuleName', ['ng-admin', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: I tried like the above but it didn't work for me. 
Actually in HTML file webstorm shows "is-open" attribute is not allowed inside <input> tag.

Comment: any error shown in console?  webstorm warning not a problem  because `is-open` not a valid html attribute

Comment: not showing any error in console. Date is also not coming in "yyyy-MM-dd" format in input box.It is coming like full format date like "Sun Apr 24 2016 17:35:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".

Comment: can you make plunker demo or like other ?

Comment: Actually datepicker is working in normal pages in my project through ng-admin.But it is not working only in custom page I've made in ng-admin. That too I have not added any javascript file for bootstrap.

Comment: are you injected  `'ui.bootstrap'` as a module dependency ? @SurendraSrikakula

Comment: Actually when I include ui-bootsrap.min.js file in "index.html" and injected the 'ui.bootstrap' module custom page datepicker is working fine.But ng-admin normal page datepickers and filter popups are not working.

Comment: Absolutely you should include  `ui-bootsrap.min.js` in **index.html** file because of `ng-admin` didn't include `ui-bootsrap`. So your module will be like `angular.module('myApp', ['ng-admin', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: But if I add the ui-bootsrap.min.js in "index.html" file and also 'ui.bootstrap' module to "myApp", ng-admin filter dropdown and filter datepickers are not working, only custom page datepicker is working.